# Switch workspace on dual monitor 22.04

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, 22.04

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a dual monitor setup.
When I switch workspace only my main-monitor is switching. I want both to switch.
On older releases there was and option in gnome-tweaks to turn this feature on.
In my gnome-tweaks there is no workspace-section at all.
Are there any other settings available in 22.04 to make this happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This setting now made it into the "Settings" tool on the "Multitasking" tab:

[image]