# Workspace switching independently ,ubuntu 22 with multiple monitors

Tags: 22.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

How do I switch workspaces independently in ubuntu 22, while using independent monitors,just like mac and windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch workspace on dual monitor 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403554/switch-workspace-on-dual-monitor-22-04)

Comment: No, the above questions was about having multiple workspace across both screen.Switching a workspace in a monitor switches other monitor's workspace in the same direction, looking to solve this.

Comment: that's the default setting according to that question, and you can change to that setting in the same place that the linked question described. To be clear: Windows *only* allows switching workspaces on all monitors at once, MacOS allows you to switch workspaces on each monitor independently, and Ubuntu 22.04's Gnome allows you to switch all monitors at once *OR* only allow workspaces on the main monitor. You *can't* switch each monitor independently. You can choose to have no workspaces *only* on the primary monitor, or switch workspaces on *all* monitors at the same time.

Comment: @Esther your comment can be turned to an answer almost as it is.

Comment: Your title mentions 22, where Ubuntu Core 22 is a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but is still a different product. 22 can only use *snap* packages, is intended for *headless* operation where as 22.04 can use *deb* and *snap* packages, can be used on desktops & servers; ie. 22 is a more limited system than 22.04 with 22 not intended to be used by desktop users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403554/switch-workspace-on-dual-monitor-22-04), the default workspaces setting in Ubuntu 22.04 is "primary monitor only": that is, only the primary monitor switches workspaces; the rest of the monitors stay static. You can change that setting to allow *all* monitors to change workspaces *at the same time* in the `settings` app under `mulititasking`, as described in the answer to the above-linked question. There is no option to allow all monitors to switch workspaces independently of each other.

To be clear: Windows only allows switching workspaces on all monitors at once, MacOS allows you to switch workspaces on each monitor independently, and Ubuntu 22.04's Gnome allows you to switch all monitors at once OR only allow workspaces on the primary monitor. You can't switch each monitor independently. You can only choose to have workspaces only on the primary monitor, or switch workspaces on all monitors at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctrl-alt left/right` to navigate between one another. Also, `ctrl-shift-alt left/right` to move current window to the respective workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it happen by installing GNOME Tweaks with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` Then go to the *Workspaces* section, and select the *Workspaces span displays* option. Whenever you change between a window that's in another workspace it changes the workspace to all monitors.

[image: Workspaces screen on Tweaks]

Comment: Selecting the *Workspaces span displays* option does not switch workspaces independently.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4586/switch-workspaces-on-active-monitor/) GNOME Shell Extension that does the same but in a weird way.

We will still not be able to switch workspace individually. **BUT**, what the extension will do is, when you switch workspace on let's say monitor 1, both monitors' workspace will switch. But on monitor 2 after it switches, it swaps all the tasks in the other monitor's previous workspace to the new switched workspace. So even tho the switching animation is there and the order of the workspace changes, we get to tie two workspaces together.